# Path denied error when building UWP app in release

Tags: c#, uwp, release, publish

I have been having issues publishing my app. To ensure that it's not my application problem, I created a blank UWP sketch with a single text. When I build it in Debug x64 it seems to work but when I build it in Release x64 I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State    Error      
Access to the path '\\?\<My Project Path>\DeployTest\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\BuildInfo' is denied.     
DeployTest  \<My Project Path>\DeployTest\LOGGERBASEDEXECTASK
```

I have tried opening Visual Studio as an administrator but still get the same results.
This is my first UWP project and it's for internal use in my company.

Comment: You can try to create a new UWP project in other drive.

Comment: It looks [ilc.exe](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-net-native-tool-chain/) has no permission to access this folder, can you try to repair your visual studio or install latest version.

Comment: @NicoZhu i have tried this and the error still persist

Comment: it's hard to detect this problem , i tried build uwp release model in my environment, it works well,  do you have other environment for testing ?